# Get all the project list in TFS in C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs

i am making a asp.net web form in which i needed all the Projects which are there in TFS after authentication which i have already done by the below code

```
var collectionUri = new Uri("https://project.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection");

var credential = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
var teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri, credential);
teamProjectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply write a *Linq* query like this:-

```
WorkItemStore workItemStore = new WorkItemStore(teamProjectCollection);
var project = (from Project pr in workItemStore.Projects
               select pr);
```

Comment: getting error could not find the implementation of the query pattern for source type project collection

Comment: @AkhilJain - Have you added reference to `System.Linq` ? Also, plz check my update.

Comment: could u help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48802247/how-to-get-all-fields-details-of-a-workitem-by-wiql-c-sharp-asp-net

Comment: @AkhilJain - Posted an answer there. Also, accept this answer if it helped you.